# Passing PHP variable through html form

Tags: php

Hello I'm trying to make a telephone contacts list using PHP and MySQLi.

This part of the program should display a list of all contacts with a delete button next to each row. Pressing the delete button should pass the $firstname value to another page and then do some further MySqli processing.

For some reason, the $firstname variable does not get passed on to the next page.

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT first_name, last_name, tele FROM contacts");

// Column headings
print '<table border="1">';
print '<tr>';
print '<td>First name</td>';
print '<td>Last name</td>';
print '<td>Telephone number</td>';

while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
    $firstname = $row->first_name;
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$firstname.'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row->last_name.'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row->tele.'</td>';
    print '<td>
           <form action="delete.php" action="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="'.$firstname.'">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
           </form>
           </td>
           </tr>';
}

print '</table>';
```

Comment: Just going to say, deleting by first name is a bad idea. Especially how at work I have an Adam for a boss, Adam for a coworker in support, Adam as a sysop, and I myself am Adam. What if I just want to delete one of them?

Comment: oh sure I'm going to change that in the next phase. I just wanted to get it up and running first

Comment: Do you get the proper HTML output? Is the firstname there in the form when you look at the source?

And also, if you do "print_r($REQUEST)" on delete.php what do you get then? :)

Comment: I get the proper html output, I don't understand what you mean by the second question. On delete.php when I check if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) I get false

Comment: as `csaw` mentioned in his answer, `method` should be post, not the `action` twice. And @NiettheDarkAbsol has right also.

Comment: oh yeah it is in the page source Fabian

Answer (score 2):

change `<form action="delete.php" action="POST">` to `<form action="delete.php" method="POST">`

to consider, maybe put checkbox next to items to delete. then on submit delete multiple items

Comment: I would consider this a typo question, and therefore it should be closed, not answered - point out the typo in a comment ;)